# How do you break Python Flask controller flow when calling return inside a function?

Tags: python, rest, flask

I'm using Python Flask and I got defined the following function:

```
def verify_session():

    if not 'logged_in' in session:
        flash("You are not logged in.<br/>Please, log in to use our application.", "warning")
        return redirect(url_for('login_path'))
```

This is meant to be called in every controller. I know that I could use `@app.before_request` but on some places I dont want this function to be called (in the same Login page, for example) and I really dont want the function to check the excluded paths.

My problem is this: inside any Flask controller for each of the paths the first lines look like this:

```
@app.route('/web/account', methods=["GET"], endpoint="account_path")
def account():
    verify_session()
    return render_template('account')
```

But, despite I get the "You need to login" flashed message, it still returns the Account page, because the `return` inside verify_session just returns for this function.

What I need is something like `return verify_session()` but that doesn't end the controller flow unless it actually is necessary to return it.

Maybe this problem is only Python/Programming specific rather than Flask so I excuse myself and ask moderators to edit my Question accordingly. I mention Flask because it's the enviroment where I'm having the trouble.

IF more information is needed I'm willing to update. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
result = verify_session()
if not result:
   result = render_template("account")
return result
```

but really you should be using a decorator for this

```
def verify_session(fn):
  def inner(*args,**kwargs):
    if not 'logged_in' in session:
        flash("You are not logged in.<br/>Please, log in to use our application.", "warning")
        return redirect(url_for('login_path'))
    return fn(*args,**kwargs)
  return inner
```

then you would use it like

```
@app.route('/web/account', methods=["GET"], endpoint="account_path")
@verify_session  #make sure to use any decorators after the route decorator
def account():
    return render_template('account')
```

lastly ... I hope you are aware that you are reinventing the wheel and you should probably just use `flask-login` to manage this stuff(unless you have a pretty compelling reason not to)

Comment: I actually didnt know about Flask-login. Anyways we have already deploy all our login/register methods and I think we are not going back to use it. Thanks for the info tho it will be very useful in future. About decorator, I'll have a try and update the question accordingly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Joran's excellent answer. Instead of using `@app.before_request`, you can put your login required routes in a [blueprint](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/blueprints/) and then use `@blueprint.before_request`:

```
account = Blueprint('account', __name__)

@account.before_request
def verify_session():
    ...

@account.route('/')
def index():
    ...
```

Then in your app:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(account, url_prefix='/web/account')
```